# Did Delphi ever get a for each loop?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, foreach

I've read that Delphi was supposed to get a for each loop in Delphi 9. Did this functionality ever make it into the language? My Delphi 2009 IDE doesn't seem to recognize the for each syntax. Here's my code:

```
  procedure ProcessDirectory(p_Directory, p_Output : string);
  var
    files : TStringList;
    filePath : string;
  begin
    files := GetSubfiles(p_Directory);
    try
      for (filePath in files.Strings) do
      begin
        // do something
      end;

    finally
      files.Free;
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: You've got it exactly right, except for the parentheses.  Remove them and it should work.

Comment: @Mason: not quite right - he should only use files, not files.strings!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
procedure ProcessDirectory(p_Directory, p_Output : string); 
var 
  files : TStringList; 
  filePath : string; 
begin 
  files := GetSubfiles(p_Directory); 
  try 
    for filePath in files do 
    begin 
      // do something 
    end; 

  finally 
    files.Free; 
  end; 
end;
```

Answer (score 29):

Yes.

But it is **for..in**

Try

```
var
  s: string;
  c: char;

begin
  s:=' Delphi Rocks!';
  for c in s do  //<--- here is the interesting part
  begin
    Application.MainForm.Caption:=Application.MainForm.Caption+c;
    Sleep(400); //delay a little to see how it works
  end;
```

Comment: I thought they opted for for .. in instead of for .. each in order to not add another reserved keyword. In is already a reserved keyword.

Comment: Plausible, but more likely is that the "each" in "for each" would not replace "in" but be a redundant addition ("for each .. in", vs "for .. in").  So not just a new keyword, but an entirely unnecessary one.